# Output width and heigh with transposed convolution

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have an input of shape `torch.Size([4, 256, 1, 5]` and I want to upsample it to `torch.Size([4, 256, 2, 11])` using `torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(ip_sz, op_sz, kernel_size, stride, padding, output_padding)`

I tried different combinations of `kernel_size, stride, padding, output_padding` however, I am unable to get the desired result.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Dummy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ip_sz, op_sz, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1):
        super(Dummy, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(ip_sz, op_sz, kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                        stride=stride, padding=padding, output_padding=output_padding)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        print(x.shape)
        return x

dummy_model = Dummy(256, 256)
dummy_model(torch.rand([4, 256, 1, 5]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolution with following parameters should work:

```
new_dummy = Dummy(256, 256, kernel_size=(2, 3), stride=2, padding=0, output_padding=0)
```

Comment: Please, can you elaborate on how you get this result (some formula, multiple trials, experience)?

Comment: Height in input is 1, but in output its 2, so clearly kernel height should be 2. WIth width it's not so clear, but after trying kernel width of 3 and stride 2 (because width in output more than twice than in input), and no padding it worked (so just trying out). This [tutorial](https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/transposed-conv.html) should give good intuition how transposed convolutions works.